# How to change the root view background in a managed expo app?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

With the introduction of Page Sheets in iOS 13, there is a white background in my app that I cannot seem to be able to change (behind the white Page Sheet, and the grey top of the underlying page):

[image: Example of issue]

Obviously, for most apps a black background color would look much better.

While for ejected React Native apps, one could use:

https://github.com/johniak/react-native-root-view-background

I'm curious if anyone using managed Expo has figured out a way to deal with this. As I cannot find much complaints about this issue, other than:

https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/1563

Answer (score 8):

For anyone out there who's using `@react-navigation` and looking for a way to change the background color of the root view between tab changes: simply add `backgroundColor` prop to `app.json`:

```json
"backgroundColor": "#000000",
```

Might work in other scenarios as well.

Comment: Not working. Can you please show the full code

Comment: No sorry. If you're using @react-navigation and you want to style the root view, this change in app.json works. If it doesn't work for you, your problem lies elsewhere. Try to debug the native view with Flipper and see which element has unwanted background. Good luck.

Comment: thank u for your solution (answer). That is right but we need to install expo-system-ui to make it work.

Comment: this does work, but is there a way to specify it later in the code so that it can follow the app 'theme' ?

Answer (score 7):

There is an simple trick using navigator...

```
<NavigationContainer>
   <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
         cardStyle: {
            backgroundColor: 'Your_Color_Here',
         },
      }}
   >
      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} />
   </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

You can use cardStyle to change default white backgroundColor to your desire backgroundColor. I hope this answer helps use it works for me.

Comment: works if you update cardStyle to contentStyle

Answer (score 3):

To change your root background in Expo managed apps, refer to [expo-system-ui](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/system-ui/)

```
SystemUI.setBackgroundColorAsync("white");
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using react-navigation 5.x with `createNativeStackNavigator` and then using `presentation:"modal"` in your screen options. I could not find a way to set a black background the on the root view with this type of navigator.

Here's what I ended up doing :

- create a standard StackNavigator with `createStackNavigator`, with `mode='modal'` property.
- put all my modals within this navigator at the root of my app with `...TransitionPresets.ModalPresentationIOS` in my screen options. This mimics the behavior you are looking for, as createStackNavigator respects the *backgroundColor* property set in your app.json file for it's root view.

I came up with this solution after finding this Snack (https://snack.expo.io/@satya164/modal-presentation-style-in-react-navigation). This is far from perfect but the best I could do for now using managed Expo. With nesting navigators, I keep using `createNativeStackNavigator` for push navigators to get nice, native push transitions for anything other than modals.